# solving for $x$ in Normal distribution problem

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a problem that says:

$X\sim N(8, 5^2)$. Find $x$ so that...

$$P(-x \leq X-8 \leq x) = .35$$

First the solution divided all sides by 5, then went straight to $2F(x/5) - 1 = .35.$

I know this a symmetry rule but I don't think I'm understanding all the steps to get there. When I do it manually I get $z \leq x/5 = F(x/5),$ and $z \leq -x/5 = 1-F(-x/5) = 1-(1-F(x/5) = 2F(x/5) = .35.$

but the final solution says its $2F(x/5) - 1 = .35.$ I use this process after reviewing my notes, but maybe I'm not understanding something fundamental about this process? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you'd use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your math, your question will get more attention.

Comment: sorry I'm having enough trouble learning all of this material right here within the next few hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

By definition,
\begin{equation}
\Phi(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{z}f(y)dy = 1-\int_{-\infty}^{-z}f(y)dy=1-\Phi(-z)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(-z<Z<z)=\Phi(z)-\Phi(-z)=\Phi(z)-(1-\Phi(z))=2\Phi(z)-1
\end{equation}

Comment: I see. I somehow forgot I was supposed to subtract the two.. thanks